# The conditional operator is not allowing the program to terminate

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, conditional-operator, termination

I just learnt about conditional operators and was doing an introductory exercise stating:

> Write a program to use a conditional operator to find the elements in
>   a `vector<int>` that have odd value and double the value of each such
>   element.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> nums = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    int i;
    auto beg = nums.begin();

    while (*beg > 0) // This will always evaluate to true. 
    { 
        ((*beg) % 2 == 0 && (beg < nums.end()) ? i = 0 : *beg = 2 * (*(beg++)));
        /*If the number is even the program will just assign 0 to i*/
    }
}
```

The program terminates AND gives you the correct output if you change the last line to:

```
((*beg)%2 == 0 && (beg < nums.end()) ? i = 0 : *beg = 2*(*(beg))); 
++beg;
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because in in the first version the increment is called only if `((*beg)%2 == 0 && (beg < nums.end())` is `false`, so your program get stuck. In the second version the increment is always called

Comment: @ButiriDan Why would it get stuck? It can always assign i to 0 if the condition turned out to be true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stuck because, if the condition `((*beg)%2 == 0 && (beg < nums.end())` is `true`, the iterator will not increment for checking further. You have only setting `i=0`. You should increment the iterator as well.

You can use *[comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)* for this:

```
while (beg != nums.end()  && *beg > 0)
{
    (*beg) % 2 == 0  ? (beg++, i): (*beg = 2 * (*beg) , beg++, ++i );
}
```

Also note that the count `i` should be initialized before-hand, not in the `while` loop.
The complete working code as per the requirement would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    int i{0};
    auto beg = nums.begin();

    while (beg != nums.end()  && *beg > 0)
    {
        (*beg) % 2 == 0  ? (beg++, i): (*beg = 2 * (*beg) , beg++, ++i );
    }
    for (const int ele : nums)
            std::cout << ele << " ";
    std::cout << "\ncount: " << i << "\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
2 2 6 4 10 6 14 8 18 
count: 5
```

---

That being said, IMO using comma operator along with conditional operator like the above(the task) is not a good coding manner, which will only make confusions for the future readers of your codebase.

Also read: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to double some values and not others, just do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    for (int& num : nums)
        num = num % 2 ? 2 * num : num;
    for (int num : nums)
        std::cout << num << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

A conditional expression is an **expression**; you use it to compute a value. The code in the question does not do that; it uses the conditional expression as a way of selecting side effects, which is better done with an ordinary `if` statement.